# Проблема с boost

Tags: c++, boost

Компилирую проект с бустом. Компилируется нормально, при линковке постоянно вылетает ошибка:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_program_options-vc100-mt-sgd-1_64.lib'

Погуглил, толкового ответа не нашел.
Подскажите, что за библиотека и где ее взять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы скачали готовый Boost, то этот файл в него входит. Он лежит в каталоге `lib64-msvc-10.0`. Не забывайте линковать его в проект.

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от настроек основного проекта при использовании Boost в Visual Studio могут запрашиваться разные имена файлов библиотек для линковки. В данном случае имя:

```
libboost_program_options-vc100-mt-sgd-1_64.lib
```

[расшифровывается](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming) следующими образом:

- `lib` - префикс библиотеки
- `boost_program_options` - имя библиотеки
- `vc100` - Visual Studio v10.0 (2010)
- `mt` - поддержка многопоточности
- `s` - статическая линковка к стандартной библиотеке
- `g` - использование отладочной версии стандартной библиотеки
- `d` - сборка самой библиотеки с отладкой
- `1_64` - версия библиотеки
- `.lib` - расширение для статической или библиотеки импорта

Чтобы получить эту библиотеку её нужно собрать (т.к. Boost не на 100% состоит из header-only библиотек). Процедура сборки [подробно описана на сайте Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary).

Comment: Буст у меня собран, но этой библиотеки нет. Спасибо за линк, но я не нашел, как собрать именно эту библиотеку.